# How can I rsync files to a folder in a way that they can't be deleted by the user that wrote them?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm adding a long-term archive to my home environment. It's a separate ZFS filesystem that only a special user has write access to: others have read-only access. The main requirements are that only the special user `archive` has write access to the filesystem (using rsync) and that once files have been written, only `root` can delete them (i.e. once written, files become read-only to *all* users).

Each "session" will create a new folder hierarchy in the archive, using the current date-time as the folder name. I'm making use of compression and deduplication on the ZFS filesystem to cope with the fact that the same file may get archived many times.

I've written a bash script for this (I could use python) but I'm having trouble setting folder permissions, umask settings etc to enforce the "write-once" requirement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain in more details how you see the required permissions. From what I could understand you probably just want to rsync using root/sudo and have the read permission for all users.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve may not be so out of the box. I want `archive` to be able to write files into a new folder (named after the archive date-time), but once written, that folder heirarchy becomes read-only to all users (ecept root of course).

The reason is paranoia on my part :-) I've suffered too many "lost files" in the past due to software errors that accidentally delete or corrupt files, but do it silently so that backup versions become corrupted as well over time.

Comment: I think the answer is to have another step in the script that runs after rsync and changes all the modes to 444 (555 for directories)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, that your user `archive`needs write permissions on all directories in the archive. That means that with normal Unix permissions, `archive` is also able to delete them. So, you may want to accept that the user archive has also delete capabilities.

Giving an umask of 0022 to `archive` should make it all readable for everyone and should not allow anyone to delete the files. You may want to look at the `rscync` arguments `--no-perms`,  `--no-owner` and  `--no-group`, if you did not already.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering if a combination of --no-perms and --chmod might do something. e.g. --no-perms --chmod=ug-w. However, this may prevent rsync writing files ino newly created folders.

Comment: An option would be to have a staging-area where users can rsync their data to and a separate archive . That is what I do.  Every night I backup to the staging-area, and in the morning I copy the staging area with `cp -bruv` to the archive. You can do that more often if you like.

Comment: A staging area might be the way to go.

Comment: As each session is to a new folder in the root of the archive then provided I can assume no session will be in progress at xxAM in the morning, I can run a cron job that either: changes the ownership of the files to (e.g.) root; or, removes all 'w' permissions.